# Missing files while leveraging native extensions on Ruby docker image

Tags: ruby, docker, debian

While attempting to prepare a Dockerfile for use with Ruby, I'm getting a list of files that are unable to be found on the underlying OS image

the main errors appear to be

- while installing "bond", which is used for the "tux" gem

  - checking for `-lstdc++`... *** extconf.rb failed ***
- while installing "bson" which is an underlying dependency for mongoid (mongodb)

  - checking for `unistd.h`... *** extconf.rb failed ***

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ruby:3.1.2-slim-buster as base

WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock

FROM base as dev
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
```

```bash
docker build --tag app .
[+] Building 8.4s (13/14)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 264B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.4s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:443aab4ca21183e069e7d8b2dc68006594f40bddf1b15bbd83f5137bd93e80e2                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ruby:3.1.2-slim-buster                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.4s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 17.46kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [base 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/ruby:3.1.2-slim-buster@sha256:083bf173b20e912a04b289f2b251bb8af9e563ad8a3f6fdeb1c10748704a8640                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [base 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [base 3/4] COPY Gemfile Gemfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [base 4/4] COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [dev 1/2] RUN bundle install                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     7.4s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 > [dev 1/2] RUN bundle install:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#11 1.108 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#11 2.443 Resolving dependencies...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#11 2.663 Using rake 13.0.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#11 2.666 Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#11 2.669 Fetching minitest 5.16.2
#11 2.669 Fetching builder 3.2.4
#11 2.669 Fetching erubi 1.10.0
#11 2.669 Using racc 1.6.0
#11 2.669 Fetching crass 1.0.6
#11 2.669 Fetching bond 0.5.1
#11 2.669 Fetching ast 2.4.2
#11 2.676 Fetching bson 4.15.0
#11 2.729 Installing erubi 1.10.0
#11 2.731 Installing builder 3.2.4
#11 2.745 Installing ast 2.4.2
#11 2.752 Installing crass 1.0.6
#11 2.771 Installing bond 0.5.1 with native extensions
#11 2.793 Installing minitest 5.16.2
#11 2.810 Using bundler 2.3.7
#11 2.813 Fetching coderay 1.1.3
#11 2.820 Fetching rubyzip 2.3.2
#11 2.844 Installing bson 4.15.0 with native extensions
#11 2.863 Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
#11 2.866 Fetching unf_ext 0.0.8.2
#11 2.876 Installing rubyzip 2.3.2
#11 2.896 Installing coderay 1.1.3
#11 2.954 Fetching dotenv 2.7.6
#11 3.006 Installing dotenv 2.7.6
#11 3.066 Fetching dry-inflector 0.3.0
#11 3.070 Fetching gibberish 2.1.1
#11 3.088 Installing unf_ext 0.0.8.2 with native extensions
#11 3.096 Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.5
#11 3.102 Fetching rack 2.2.4
#11 3.109 Installing dry-inflector 0.3.0
#11 3.125 Installing gibberish 2.1.1
#11 3.146 Fetching multi_json 1.15.0
#11 3.173 Installing rack 2.2.4
#11 3.196 Installing multi_json 1.15.0
#11 3.200 Fetching http-accept 1.7.0
#11 3.220 Fetching jwt 2.4.1
#11 3.249 Installing http-accept 1.7.0
#11 3.270 Installing jwt 2.4.1
#11 3.288 Fetching kaminari-core 1.2.2
#11 3.318 Fetching method_source 1.0.0
#11 3.332 Installing kaminari-core 1.2.2
#11 3.342 Fetching mime-types-data 3.2022.0105
#11 3.369 Installing method_source 1.0.0
#11 3.451 Fetching netrc 0.11.0
#11 3.458 Installing mime-types-data 3.2022.0105
#11 3.482 Fetching newrelic_rpm 8.9.0
#11 3.490 Installing netrc 0.11.0
#11 3.500 Fetching nio4r 2.5.8
#11 3.569 Fetching parallel 1.22.1
#11 3.585 Fetching rainbow 3.1.1
#11 3.592 Installing nio4r 2.5.8 with native extensions
#11 3.605 Fetching regexp_parser 2.5.0
#11 3.613 Installing parallel 1.22.1
#11 3.624 Installing rainbow 3.1.1
#11 3.638 Using rexml 3.2.5
#11 3.639 Fetching ruby-progressbar 1.11.0
#11 3.662 Fetching unicode-display_width 2.2.0
#11 3.676 Installing newrelic_rpm 8.9.0
#11 3.679 Fetching tilt 2.0.10
#11 3.680 Installing ruby-progressbar 1.11.0
#11 3.708 Installing unicode-display_width 2.2.0
#11 3.725 Installing tilt 2.0.10
#11 3.727 Installing regexp_parser 2.5.0
#11 3.753 Fetching nokogiri 1.13.7 (x86_64-linux)
#11 3.798 Fetching parser 3.0.2.0
#11 3.864 Fetching mustermann 1.1.2
#11 3.936 Fetching pry 0.14.1
#11 3.970 Fetching rack-accept 0.4.5
#11 3.981 Installing mustermann 1.1.2
#11 4.001 Installing rack-accept 0.4.5
#11 4.181 Fetching rack-contrib 2.3.0
#11 4.213 Installing rack-contrib 2.3.0
#11 4.229 Installing parser 3.0.2.0
#11 4.235 Fetching rack-cors 1.1.1
#11 4.245 Installing pry 0.14.1
#11 4.267 Fetching rack-protection 2.2.1
#11 4.285 Fetching rack-test 1.0.0
#11 4.307 Installing rack-protection 2.2.1
#11 4.315 Installing rack-cors 1.1.1
#11 4.325 Installing rack-test 1.0.0
#11 4.327 Fetching i18n 1.12.0
#11 4.374 Installing i18n 1.12.0
#11 4.397 Fetching tzinfo 2.0.5
#11 4.404 Fetching dry-container 0.10.0
#11 4.437 Installing dry-container 0.10.0
#11 4.447 Fetching dry-core 0.8.0
#11 4.468 Installing tzinfo 2.0.5
#11 4.498 Installing dry-core 0.8.0
#11 4.550 Fetching mime-types 3.4.1
#11 4.564 Fetching mustermann-grape 1.0.2
#11 4.603 Installing mime-types 3.4.1
#11 4.609 Fetching sinatra 2.2.1
#11 4.614 Installing mustermann-grape 1.0.2
#11 4.682 Fetching dry-logic 1.2.0
#11 4.688 Fetching activesupport 7.0.3.1
#11 4.735 Installing dry-logic 1.2.0
#11 4.788 Installing sinatra 2.2.1
#11 4.799 Installing activesupport 7.0.3.1
#11 4.833 Fetching dry-types 1.5.1
#11 4.880 Installing dry-types 1.5.1
#11 4.981 Fetching rubocop-ast 1.15.2
#11 5.074 Installing rubocop-ast 1.15.2
#11 5.259 Fetching rubocop 1.10.0
#11 5.260 Installing nokogiri 1.13.7 (x86_64-linux)
#11 5.355 Fetching grape 1.6.2
#11 5.357 Fetching grape-entity 0.10.1
#11 5.359 Fetching activemodel 7.0.3.1
#11 5.359 Fetching phoner 1.0.1
#11 5.399 Installing phoner 1.0.1
#11 5.451 Installing grape-entity 0.10.1
#11 5.460 Installing activemodel 7.0.3.1
#11 5.492 Installing rubocop 1.10.0
#11 5.508 Installing grape 1.6.2
#11 5.639 Fetching activerecord 7.0.3.1
#11 5.769 Installing activerecord 7.0.3.1
#11 6.184 Fetching grape-swagger 1.4.2
#11 6.186 Fetching grape_logging 1.8.4
#11 6.260 Installing grape_logging 1.8.4
#11 6.315 Installing grape-swagger 1.4.2
#11 6.687 Fetching grape-swagger-entity 0.5.1
#11 6.715 Installing grape-swagger-entity 0.5.1
#11 6.798 Fetching kaminari-activerecord 1.2.2
#11 6.836 Installing kaminari-activerecord 1.2.2
#11 6.913 Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
#11 6.914 Fetching loofah 2.18.0
#11 6.916 Fetching creek 2.5.3
#11 6.919 Fetching sanitize 6.0.0
#11 6.956 Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
#11 6.958 Installing loofah 2.18.0
#11 6.972 Installing sanitize 6.0.0
#11 6.985 Installing creek 2.5.3
#11 7.019 Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.3
#11 7.045 Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.3
#11 7.061 Fetching actionview 7.0.3.1
#11 7.120 Installing actionview 7.0.3.1
#11 7.154 Fetching kaminari-actionview 1.2.2
#11 7.178 Installing kaminari-actionview 1.2.2
#11 7.207 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 current directory:
#11 7.207 /usr/local/bundle/gems/bond-0.5.1/ext/readline_line_buffer
#11 7.207 /usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r
#11 7.207 ./siteconf20220721-7-tppqi4.rb extconf.rb
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/bond-0.5.1/ext/readline_line_buffer
#11 7.207 make DESTDIR\= clean
#11 7.207 current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/bond-0.5.1/ext/readline_line_buffer
#11 7.207 make DESTDIR\=
#11 7.207 make failedNo such file or directory - make
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/bond-0.5.1 for
#11 7.207 inspection.
#11 7.207 Results logged to
#11 7.207 /usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/bond-0.5.1/gem_make.out
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:70:in `rescue in run'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:67:in `run'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:44:in `block in make'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in `each'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in `make'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:63:in `block in
#11 7.207 build'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tempfile.rb:317:in `open'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in `build'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `build_extension'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `block in
#11 7.207 build_extensions'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `each'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `build_extensions'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:853:in `build_extensions'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:71:in
#11 7.207 `build_extensions'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in `install'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:204:in `install'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
#11 7.207 `install_from_spec'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in
#11 7.207 `do_install'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in
#11 7.207 `block in worker_pool'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in
#11 7.207 create_threads'
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 An error occurred while installing bond (0.5.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 In Gemfile:
#11 7.207   tux was resolved to 0.3.0, which depends on
#11 7.207     ripl-multi_line was resolved to 0.3.1, which depends on
#11 7.207       ripl was resolved to 0.7.1, which depends on
#11 7.207         bond
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207     current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/bson-4.15.0/ext/bson
#11 7.207 /usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r
#11 7.207 ./siteconf20220721-7-k7nugp.rb extconf.rb
#11 7.207 creating Makefile
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/bson-4.15.0/ext/bson
#11 7.207 make DESTDIR\= clean
#11 7.207 current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/bson-4.15.0/ext/bson
#11 7.207 make DESTDIR\=
#11 7.207 make failedNo such file or directory - make
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/bson-4.15.0 for
#11 7.207 inspection.
#11 7.207 Results logged to
#11 7.207 /usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/bson-4.15.0/gem_make.out
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:70:in `rescue in run'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:67:in `run'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:44:in `block in make'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in `each'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in `make'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:63:in `block in
#11 7.207 build'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tempfile.rb:317:in `open'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in `build'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `build_extension'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `block in
#11 7.207 build_extensions'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `each'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `build_extensions'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:853:in `build_extensions'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:71:in
#11 7.207 `build_extensions'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in `install'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:204:in `install'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
#11 7.207 `install_from_spec'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in
#11 7.207 `do_install'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in
#11 7.207 `block in worker_pool'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in
#11 7.207 create_threads'
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 An error occurred while installing bson (4.15.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 In Gemfile:
#11 7.207   kaminari-mongoid was resolved to 1.0.2, which depends on
#11 7.207     mongoid was resolved to 8.0.1, which depends on
#11 7.207       mongo was resolved to 2.18.0, which depends on
#11 7.207         bson
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207     current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/unf_ext-0.0.8.2/ext/unf_ext
#11 7.207 /usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r
#11 7.207 ./siteconf20220721-7-2qzffz.rb extconf.rb
#11 7.207 checking for -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed ***
#11 7.207 Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
#11 7.207 libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
#11 7.207 need configuration options.
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 Provided configuration options:
#11 7.207   --with-opt-dir
#11 7.207   --without-opt-dir
#11 7.207   --with-opt-include
#11 7.207   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
#11 7.207   --with-opt-lib
#11 7.207   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
#11 7.207   --with-make-prog
#11 7.207   --without-make-prog
#11 7.207   --srcdir=.
#11 7.207   --curdir
#11 7.207   --ruby=/usr/local/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
#11 7.207   --with-static-libstdc++
#11 7.207   --without-static-libstdc++
#11 7.207   --with-stdc++-dir
#11 7.207   --without-stdc++-dir
#11 7.207   --with-stdc++-include
#11 7.207   --without-stdc++-include=${stdc++-dir}/include
#11 7.207   --with-stdc++-lib
#11 7.207   --without-stdc++-lib=${stdc++-dir}/lib
#11 7.207   --with-stdc++lib
#11 7.207   --without-stdc++lib
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:498:in `try_do': The compiler failed to
#11 7.207 generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
#11 7.207 You have to install development tools first.
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:591:in `try_link0'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:609:in `try_link'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:837:in `try_func'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1065:in `block in have_library'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1007:in `block in checking_for'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:362:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:332:in `open'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:362:in `block in postpone'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:332:in `open'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:358:in `postpone'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1006:in `checking_for'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1060:in `have_library'
#11 7.207   from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
#11 7.207 be found here:
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207   /usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/unf_ext-0.0.8.2/mkmf.log
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 extconf failed, exit code 1
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/unf_ext-0.0.8.2 for
#11 7.207 inspection.
#11 7.207 Results logged to
#11 7.207 /usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/unf_ext-0.0.8.2/gem_make.out
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:95:in `run'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:47:in `block in
#11 7.207 build'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tempfile.rb:317:in `open'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in `build'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `build_extension'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `block in
#11 7.207 build_extensions'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `each'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `build_extensions'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:853:in `build_extensions'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:71:in
#11 7.207 `build_extensions'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in `install'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:204:in `install'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
#11 7.207 `install_from_spec'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in
#11 7.207 `do_install'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in
#11 7.207 `block in worker_pool'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in
#11 7.207 create_threads'
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.8.2), and Bundler cannot
#11 7.207 continue.
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 In Gemfile:
#11 7.207   rest-client was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
#11 7.207     http-cookie was resolved to 1.0.5, which depends on
#11 7.207       domain_name was resolved to 0.5.20190701, which depends on
#11 7.207         unf was resolved to 0.1.4, which depends on
#11 7.207           unf_ext
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207     current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/nio4r-2.5.8/ext/nio4r
#11 7.207 /usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r
#11 7.207 ./siteconf20220721-7-civmo2.rb extconf.rb
#11 7.207 checking for unistd.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
#11 7.207 Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
#11 7.207 libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
#11 7.207 need configuration options.
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 Provided configuration options:
#11 7.207   --with-opt-dir
#11 7.207   --without-opt-dir
#11 7.207   --with-opt-include
#11 7.207   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
#11 7.207   --with-opt-lib
#11 7.207   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
#11 7.207   --with-make-prog
#11 7.207   --without-make-prog
#11 7.207   --srcdir=.
#11 7.207   --curdir
#11 7.207   --ruby=/usr/local/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
#11 7.207   --with-unistd-dir
#11 7.207   --without-unistd-dir
#11 7.207   --with-unistd-include
#11 7.207   --without-unistd-include=${unistd-dir}/include
#11 7.207   --with-unistd-lib
#11 7.207   --without-unistd-lib=${unistd-dir}/lib
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:498:in `try_do': The compiler failed to
#11 7.207 generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
#11 7.207 You have to install development tools first.
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:624:in `block in try_compile'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:573:in `with_werror'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:624:in `try_compile'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1160:in `block in have_header'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1007:in `block in checking_for'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:362:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:332:in `open'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:362:in `block in postpone'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:332:in `open'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:358:in `postpone'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1006:in `checking_for'
#11 7.207   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1159:in `have_header'
#11 7.207   from extconf.rb:15:in `<main>'
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
#11 7.207 be found here:
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207   /usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/nio4r-2.5.8/mkmf.log
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 extconf failed, exit code 1
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/nio4r-2.5.8 for
#11 7.207 inspection.
#11 7.207 Results logged to
#11 7.207 /usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/nio4r-2.5.8/gem_make.out
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:95:in `run'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:47:in `block in
#11 7.207 build'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tempfile.rb:317:in `open'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in `build'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `build_extension'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `block in
#11 7.207 build_extensions'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `each'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `build_extensions'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:853:in `build_extensions'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:71:in
#11 7.207 `build_extensions'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in `install'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:204:in `install'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
#11 7.207 `install_from_spec'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in
#11 7.207 `do_install'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in
#11 7.207 `block in worker_pool'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
#11 7.207   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
#11 7.207 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in
#11 7.207 create_threads'
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 An error occurred while installing nio4r (2.5.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
#11 7.207 
#11 7.207 In Gemfile:
#11 7.207   puma was resolved to 5.6.4, which depends on
#11 7.207     nio4r
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c bundle install]: exit code: 5
make: *** [image] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving by moving to a different image, I assume `thin` will not work. I went with the `buster` image instead of `slim-buster`

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ruby:3.1.2-buster as base

WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock

FROM base as dev
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
```